# Why are ta.change and request.security functions not synchronising to a fixed candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to work with ta.change and request.security but I am confused by some of the unpredictable behaviours!

I assumed ta.change and request.security would synchronise smoothly when they use the same length of time but I have had problems:

_I first noticed there was a delay of one candle between both as seen in the image attached (red vs green dots). I also attached the code in question that will replicate these plotshapes.
_Secondly, I noticed the end of the candle's timestamp isn't fixed to a set time each day when using request.security. I don't understand the logic and it makes the script unpredictable. I've attached two images, the ones with green lines where in the first example, the time of change is 8.25am and one week later it is 8.30am. This also means the green dot is plotting on the same candle as the red dot (sometimes).
_Lastly, similar to the above example, when I check the time of change at one moment, I could have a different result a few minutes/hours later after another check... more unpredictability. It feels very random

What explains the candle difference/shift between red and green dot? Is there a way to ensure they are synchronised at all times, either fixed to the same candle or ensure they are one candle apart at all times?

From my observations, it seems like newPeriod moves like clockwork and stays consistent throughout the day however periodCheck is a bit less predictable and will pick and choose a random candle (8.25am vs 8.30am).

Later on in my IF statements I was planning on using newPeriod = ta.change(time("90")) to set orders with strategy.entry based on values of the highs and lows of the last period but given that there's some unpredicatibility and this candle delay between newPeriod and periodCheck maybe I should just use periodCheck instead to negate this issue? I am starting to think I shouldn't even be using newPeriod anymore despite periodCheck being less reliable...

I hope this makes sense, it's a bit tough to explain this clearly!

[Red vs Green dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKV9C.png)

[8.25am 19th June](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flYng.png) vs
[8.30am 26th June](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0d3G.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("ta.change vs request.security", overlay=true)

// Get previous highs and lows
periodHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "90", high[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
periodLow  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "90", low[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])

// Draw data to the chart
plot(periodHigh, color=color.green, title="Last Period's High")
plot(periodLow, color=color.green, title="Last Period's Low")

// New Period change
newPeriod = ta.change(time("90"))

// Testing / Debugging
periodCheck = periodHigh != periodHigh[1]

plotshape(newPeriod ? true : na, color=color.green, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(periodCheck ? true : na, color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.circle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request.security() function in your example will behave differently on historical and real-time candles and eventually will repaint the results once recalculated on the historical dataset.

To avoid repainting and match with the timechange function, offset the values and use the lookahead parameter:

```
periodHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "90", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
periodLow  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "90", low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks e2e4! Really appreciate your time and input here as I know my question was confusing. Cheers